# What is my Arduino picking up on?

Tags: arduino

[[image]

I can't figure out what my Arduino is picking up on. The waves seem to be fairly consistent, and this is representing data from the analog pins. The blue is A5, which has a copper wire sticking out to function as an antenna.

Does anyone have any ideas? Does anyone know? The signal seems to get clearer when I get closer, but it doesn't matter how far away I get.

My code is:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("a = ");
  Serial.print(analogRead(0));
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print("b = ");
  Serial.print(analogRead(1));
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print("c = ");
  Serial.print(analogRead(2));
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print("d = ");
  Serial.print(analogRead(3));
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print("e = ");
  Serial.print(analogRead(4));
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print("f = ");
  Serial.print(analogRead(5));
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: What is the timescale on the X axis?

Comment: This question seems better suited for [ee.se](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MatteoItalia, IDK, I included my code, if it helps.

Comment: What are you trying to do/make?

Comment: I bet you the frequency is close to 50 or 60Hz.  Depending on where you live.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an electrical engineering question.

Comment: @gre_gor you are right. I'm voting too... *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just picking up garbage (EMI?) with that wire. Just inserting a wire into your Arduino doesn't mean you have a *real* antenna. Antenna's have specific impedances in order to work at discrete frequencies.

On logical pins you usually use pull-ups or pull-downs in order to avoid that sort of things (floating states).

It would be interesting to know if the 600 you are measuring is millivolts or microvolts. I guess it is microvolts...

Have you considered [tying it down to ground with 10k](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70009/why-use-a-pull-down-resistor-with-a-ldr-and-microcontroller) in case you want to get rid of it?

Comment: I realize it's not actually an antenna, I was working on a different project, and I came across this. I was just wondering what it was.

Comment: A piece of wire _is_ an antenna.